# Configuring yahoo messenger on iChat

Tags: ichat

Is it possible to configure **Yahoo Messenger** on **iChat**? There are options in iChat to configure Google talk, yahoo messenger, AOL etc. So far I know it is possible to configure Google talk. But I did not get any document or evidence to configure Yahoo Messenger. I do not know why? Is it possible to fix this problem??? I am talking about **Mac OS X Lion**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to sign up for a Yahoo! account by going [here](https://edit.yahoo.com/registration?.src=fpctx&.intl=us&.done=http://www.yahoo.com/).

Once you have done that, you can configure Yahoo Messenger in iChat by doing the following:

- Open iChat
- Open iChat Preferences by going to the menu item iChat > Preferences or by hitting <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> on your keyboard
- Go to Accounts
- Click the **+** button
- Select "Yahoo" from the drop down menu under Account Type:

[image]

- Authenticate using your Yahoo account credentials
- Enjoy using iChat with Yahoo.

Answer (score 0):

This method works for text chat. iChat claims to support video and SMS via Yahoo, but used the method above to configure Yahoo, and I got no option for video chat. Any more ideas?

Comment: If you are not attempting to answer the question you should consider posting your own question or writing a comment.